# NgRx read current state property inside metareducer

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to read userId(state property) inside metaredcuer. Is that possible? For example:

```
export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return function(state, action) {

    let userId: number = state.user.id; // Is this possible wihtout subscrition? 
    
    ...
  };
}
```

Comment: yes - thats exactly how you can access it ... i mean maybe run the code first ^^

Comment: @jonathanHeindl my bad I was importing it as state: State<Appstate>.